# How to mock void method using EasyMock and then how to test it using assert?

Tags: java, unit-testing, easymock

I need to unit test a function, which makes an inner call of another `void` method.

```
Class TestClass {
    public void testMethod() {
        someOtherClass.testMethod(); // This is void method 
    }
}
```

I need to mock `someOtherClass.testMethod()` and then verify `testMethod` of `TestClass` using assert.

---

Sorry for my post if it is confusing. Let me make it more clear. My intention is -

```
public void testMethodTest() { 
  TestClass tC = new TestClass(); SomeOtherClass obj = EasyMock.createNiceMock(SomeOtherClass.class); 
  tC.set(obj); 
  obj.testMethod(); 
  EasyMock.expectLastCall().andAnswer(new IAnswer() { 
     public Object answer() { // return the value to be returned by the method (null for void) 
       return null; 
     }
  }); 
  EasyMock.replay(obj); 
  tC.testMethod(); // How to verify this using assert. 
}
```

Comment: what is `someOtherClass` in relation to the class/method under test?

Comment: Do you want to verify that `someOtherClass.testMethod()` gets called on calling `testMethod()` ?

Comment: someOtherClass is instance of SomeOtherClass.java. @Vicky - Yes. I want to mock  someOtherClass.testMethod() to return some type and then calling testMethod of TestClass to match previous return type if possible

Comment: you are saying that you want to mock someOtherClass.testMethod() to return some type but it's return type is void so that isn't possible. I am not able to understand why you would want to do that. For testing `testMethod()` , verifying that `someOtherClass.testMethod`

Comment: you are saying that you want to mock someOtherClass.testMethod() to return some type but it's return type is void so that isn't possible. I am not able to understand why you would want to do that. For testing `testMethod()` , verifying that `someOtherClass.testMethod` is called exactly once is sufficient.  But to do that someOtherClass must injecteable. How is that object created. ? passed to TestClass constructor or via a setter method or does the method creates this object on it's own ?

Comment: Sorry for my post if it is confusing. Let me make it more clear. My intention is  - public void testMethodTest()  {
  TestClass  tC = new TestClass();
  SomeOtherClass  obj = EasyMock.createNiceMock(SomeOtherClass.class);
  tC.set(obj);
  obj.testMethod();
  EasyMock.expectLastCall().andAnswer(new IAnswer() {
   public Object answer() {
    // return the value to be returned by the method (null for void)
    return null;
   }
  });
  EasyMock.replay(obj);
  tC.testMethod(); // How to verify this using assert.
 }

Comment: @user3770039 [edit] the question to clarify it. Not in the comments. It is more confusing to read code in comments.

Answer (score 0):

What you wrote is working. However, it is overly complicated and you are not verifying that the void method was actually called. To do that, you need to add `EasyMock.verify(obj);` at the end.

Then, one important thing is that if you call a void method before the replay, it records a call. No need to add an `expectLastCall`. Also, you could have used `expectLastCall().andVoid()` instead of the `IAnswer`.

Here is how I would write it:

```
@Test
public void testMethodTest() {
  TestClass tC = new TestClass();
  SomeOtherClass obj = mock(SomeOtherClass.class); // no need to use a nice mock
  tC.set(obj);

  obj.testMethod();

  replay(obj);

  tC.testMethod();

  verify(obj); // Verify testMethod was called
}
```